# How can I remove/edit an anchor added with appendAnchor?

Tags: three.js, bullet, ammo.js

I'm using ammo.js with ThreeJS.  I've searched inside the get_m_cfg/set_m_cfg for clothSoftBody using the console.log command to no avail.  Is there a way to remove or edit a softbody anchor added like this?

```
clothSoftBody.appendAnchor( 0, arm.userData.physicsBody, false, influence );
clothSoftBody.appendAnchor( clothNumSegmentsZ * 0.5, arm.userData.physicsBody, false, influence );
clothSoftBody.appendAnchor( clothNumSegmentsZ, arm.userData.physicsBody, false, influence );
```

I was able to change the anchor hardness with

```
clothSoftBody.get_m_cfg().set_kAHR(0.6);
```

but I don't see a config for influence..  I'm assuming I have to access the anchor array, but I have no idea how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I was using an older version of ammo.js.  The new one from 7 days ago added get_m_anchors and set_m_anchors for soft body objects.